# command not found in pipenv path

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, pipenv

Edit: This is solved, see answer below

I'm trying to deploy some software using Docker / Jenkins for the first time and I'm running into some issues with the paths.

This is the current Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./ .
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/src/app"
RUN pipenv run echo $PATH
RUN pwd
RUN ls
RUN pipenv run whereis run
RUN pipenv run run
```

When I try to build the docker image using Jenkins, I get the following output:

```
09:19:48   ---> Running in ff1a52b2e299
09:19:48  Removing intermediate container ff1a52b2e299
09:19:48   ---> 67355de18e72
09:19:48  Step 7/11 : RUN pipenv run echo $PATH
09:19:48   ---> Running in 5cb904118910

09:19:49  /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/src/app
09:19:49  Removing intermediate container 5cb904118910
09:19:49   ---> 0df62985c94d
09:19:49  Step 8/11 : RUN pwd
09:19:49   ---> Running in 4e79f53b581f

09:19:49  /usr/src/app
09:19:50  Removing intermediate container 4e79f53b581f
09:19:50   ---> 563ab4218eba
09:19:50  Step 9/11 : RUN ls
09:19:50   ---> Running in fbc7670633d1
09:19:50  Dockerfile
09:19:50  Jenkinsfile
09:19:50  Pipfile
09:19:50  Pipfile.lock
09:19:50  README.md
09:19:50  alembic.ini
09:19:50  run.bat
09:19:50  run.sh
09:19:50  trendanalyse

09:19:51  Removing intermediate container fbc7670633d1
09:19:51   ---> 02a4b76defd0
09:19:51  Step 10/11 : RUN pipenv run whereis run
09:19:51   ---> Running in 70d5448e29b1
09:19:51  run: /usr/src/app/run.bat /usr/src/app/run.sh /usr/src/app/run.bat /usr/src/app/run.sh

09:19:52  Removing intermediate container 70d5448e29b1
09:19:52   ---> 455fc44688ce
09:19:52  Step 11/11 : RUN pipenv run run
09:19:52   ---> Running in b25bf9d5f818

09:19:52  [91mError: the command run could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].
09:19:53  [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c pipenv run run' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't see what's wrong, the run.sh file is in the current path, not sure why it won't run. It's working locally on my Windows machine, maybe it's some difference between Windows / Linux that I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues with the Dockerfile, I needed to add the line

```
RUN chmod +x run.sh
```

Additionally, I had to change

```
RUN pipenv run run
```

to

```
RUN pipenv run run.sh
```

(I think this is due to differences in Windows / Linux). Now it works :)